# Index polls portlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay

In Liferay 6.1, how one can index polls portlet to allow search portlet to retrieve old polls ?
I found answers like you need to index Polls portlet, but I'm new to Liferay and I really don't know how to proceed.

Please help me with some source code.

Thanks alot.
Halim